# What deteriorating component in my laptop is causing poor performance while playing videos

Tags: cpu, hardware, video, gpu, resources

I have a laptop which I have been using for years. I was always able to watch Youtube videos and hours-long HD videos stored on my hard drive just fine. However, recently the device started poorly performing whenever I play any video. The video playback starts smooth but after 5~10 minutes it starts "cutting" and if I let it continue it freezes the machine. I tried looking at resources and noticed the CPU usage starts off normal (around 4%) but after 10 minutes or so whatever program I am using to play the video (be it `mpv`, `mplayer`, etc) suddenly increases to something like 50%. Even when I watch a Youtube video the Web Content process goes around 40% after a few minutes of playing.

I tried playing videos with Debian, Windows and while live-booting from a Debian usb installation, all gave the same exact result. And this never happened before on any of them.

My guess is that some hardware component started having issues. I don't know how to debug this problem.

Comment: Are you noticing stuttering in performance? Significant loss of battery or overheating? 50% cpu usage is nothing to really scoff at. And in fact, if you only ever had less than 50% cpu usage you overspecced your computer and paid too much. Video playback rarely has very little to do with your desktop environment. Could you test watching a with `htop` and see were the usage is coming from?

Comment: Sorry,I was wrong.I tried playing videos with windows on the same laptop and even while live booting with a gnome debian usb and got the same results.So this has nothing to do with the desktop environment.I was deluded into thinking it was the DE because I've had this laptop for years now and it just started "cutting" and poorly performing while playing videos now.You think I should delete this question and create a new thread or should I just edit this one? I think some hardware component is deteriorating.And not only does it use a lot of cpu while playing vids,after a while it almost freezes

Comment: I think you can edit the question to be about how to troubleshoot hardware issues. How old is this laptop?

Comment: I recon it might be around 4 years old or more